# image in a <p> tag that is inside a div is coming larger than the div size

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

Hi There is problem that i am facing in only in one post of the wordpress.The image that is inside a

tag in  tag is coming bigger than the actual size of the div. because of this user is not able to differentiate between to different post.please check the image
[image]

here is the link where you can check.

[Link](http://bgp.shop-the-rock.ca/category/general/)

Comment: Set the overflow on the div to hidden.

Comment: [Use a clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/497418).

Answer (score 1):

The image is floating left so it's parent DIV ".entry-summary" needs to expand to accomodate the floating element.

To do this you need to add "overflow: hidden" to ".entry-summary".

```
.entry-summary {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You could also try `overflow: visible` if you wanted to not cut off the image, but also clear the float.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
#div img{min-width:100%;height:auto}
```

This will keep the aspect ratio, unless ofcourse you want to cut if off with the overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `float: left` to the content, like below:

```
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
text-align: justify;
width: 735px;
float: left;
}
```

This will cause the `div` to stretch around all of its contents :)